# Firestore query whereGreater on one field and OrderBy on different field

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to query all documents from collections where location field condition met withisGreaterTHenOrEqualTo and isLessThanOrEqualTo , and order those documents by descending order dending on "population" field (which is number), and get top 10 population places.

```
_firestore.collectionGroup(_collectionGroupName)
          .where("location",isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: lowGeoPoint)
          .where("location",isLessThanOrEqualTo: highGeoPoint)
          .orderBy("population", descending: true)
          .limit(10)
          .get();
```

Firestore gives exception that i need to add .orderBy("location") first, if i do so and add composite index for that query it works by just ordering docs by location and ordering by population is ingnored, but i dont want orderBy location. I want orderBy only by "population".Is there some workaround on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation in Firestore. You cannot filter by a field and after that orderby another field. they will have to be the same field. A workaroud would adding another orderby condition because this restriction is only for the first orderby. do it like:

```
_firestore.collectionGroup(_collectionGroupName)
          .where("location",isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: lowGeoPoint)
          .where("location",isLessThanOrEqualTo: highGeoPoint)
          .orderBy("location", descending: true)
          .orderBy("population", descending: true)
          .limit(10)
          .get();
```

Please, keep in mind that you need to create a composite index for this query.